# keep a random lowest value per row in a Python Pandas dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where every line is ranked on several attributes vs. all the other rows. A single line can have the same rank in 2 attributes (meaning a row can be the best in few attributes) like shown in row 2 and 3 below:

```
     att_1  att_2  att_3 att_4
ID   
984   5       3      1     46
794   1       1      99    34
6471  20      2      3     2
```

Per line, I want to keep the index (ID) and the cell with the lowest value - in case there is more than 1 cell, I have to select a random one to keep a normal distribution.

I managed to convert the df into a numpy array and run the following:

```
idx = np.argmin(h_data.values, axis=1)
```

But I get the first line every time..

Desired output:

```
ID   MIN
984   att_3
794   att_2
6471  att_1
```

Thank you!

Comment: can you give an example of your desired output?

Comment: Is this what you required? `df['min'] = (df.apply(lambda x: x.argmin() ,axis=1))`. Sohw us your expected o/p.

Comment: @Craicerjack added desired output. Apply method works but it always return the first occurrence where I need a random one. So I need per line to keep an array of the smallest rank (1 being the highest) and then choose a random one.

Comment: @Chen - Edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension with [`numpy.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

```
df['MIN'] = [np.random.choice(df.columns[x == x.min()], 1)[0] for x in df.values]
print (df)
      att_1  att_2  att_3  att_4    MIN
ID                                     
984       5      3      1     46  att_3
794       1      1     99     34  att_1
6471     20      2      3      2  att_2
```

Comment: That works! I had an error about int operator on string but managed to recover. Thank you @jezrael

Answer (score 1):

I you want to do something for each row (or column), you should try the .apply method

```
df.apply(np.argmin, axis=1) #row wise
df.apply(np.argmin, axis=0) #column wise
```

Comment: this works but doesn't return a random column when 2 identical ranks are present. (my actual data set has 20 columns with many identical ranks)